# How to get value of JS promptbox, then pass it to PHP and save it in the database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a `home_admin.php` file where the user can reject an entry with this code:

```
echo "
    <td>
        <a href=changeStatReject.php?id=" . $row['id'] . ">"  . "
            <img src='media/reject.png'>" . "
        </a>
    </td>
";
```

Once the link is clicked, it will direct the user to the `changeStatReject.php` page with the specific ID of the entry.

My goal is to show a JavaScript PromptBox asking the reason for rejecting before the code is executed.

I use this code:

```
function MyReason(){
    var reason = prompt("Reason:");
    document.getElementById("reason").value = reason;
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

Then I add this to the `home_admin.php` page:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="changeStatReject.php">
    <button onclick="MyReason()">Click Me!</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="reason" name="reason"/>
</form>
```

Even though I get the value from the prompt box, the script for the `changeStatReject` action is not working anymore.

I think there's a conflict with the `<form action="changeStatReject.php">` and `<a href=changeStatReject.php?id=" . $row['id'] . ">`

Any advice on how to get the prompt box value, save it to the database and  at the same time update (reject) the status of the specific entry?

Thanks Mates,

Comment: get value of prompt box via  `$_POST['reason']` in your PHP codes at the sever

Comment: I did that already @ABFORCE. Yes I get the value of the promptbox but the problem is the function or script to reject the entry (UPDATE) was not working anymore..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
 echo "<td> <a href= "#" onclick='myreason(".$row['id'] . "')>"  . "<img src='media/reject.png'>" . "</a></td>";
?>
.............
function MyReason(id){
    id.preventDefault();    
    var reason = prompt("Reason:");
    document.getElementById("reason").value = reason;
    document.getElementById("id").value = id;
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
.............
<form id="form" method="POST" action="changeStatReject.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" />
    <input type="hidden" id="reason" name="reason"/>
</form>
...............
Now you can handle the POST variables in your changeStatReject.php as you want.
```

Comment: Thank mate, this already solved my problem. I owe you a cup of coffee.. :)

Comment: >>> A useful advice to u my friend... While asking questions. Please try to show your full code. That's why fiddle is used here. Like you can add some fiddle to your question about "redirect Tabs". That really helps people to find a quick and better answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

add `<input type="hidden" name="id" value='id_you_need_to_pass'/>` in your form and call changeStatReject.php through this form submit.

Comment: You mean I will add this in home_admin.php? `<input type="hidden" name="id" value='id_you_need_to_pass'/>`

Comment: echo "<td> <a  onclick=\"MyReson($row['id'])\" href=" .  . ">"  . "<img src='media/reject.png'>" . "</a></td>"
    
    function MyReason(id){
        var reason = prompt("Reason:");
        document.getElementById("reason").value = reason;
        document.getElementById("id").value = id;
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
        return false;
    }